# How to make Tags and Categories Separate in django wagtail

Tags: django, blogs, wagtail

How to make Tags and Categories Separate... I have a tag for SCRC and a Tag for Libraries, but How can i make it so when I create a blog, and choose each different tag, the posts show up?
here is my models.py file. thank you for any suggestions.
This is my first django wagtail app and i am trying to create a test blog.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import deactivate_all
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from modelcluster.tags import ClusterTaggableManager
from taggit.models import Tag as TaggitTag
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (
    FieldPanel,
    FieldRowPanel,
    InlinePanel,
    MultiFieldPanel,
    PageChooserPanel,
    StreamFieldPanel,
)
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers import SnippetChooserPanel
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

class BlogsPage(Page):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [FieldPanel("description", classname="full")]


@register_snippet
class BlogsCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=80)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("name"),
        FieldPanel("slug"),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
    #How am i going to filter this categories ()

@register_snippet
class Tag(TaggitTag):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class PostPageBlogsCategory(models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey(
        "blogs.PostPage", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="categories"
    )
    blogs_category = models.ForeignKey(
        "blogs.BlogsCategory", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_pages"
    )

    panels = [
        SnippetChooserPanel("blogs_category"),
    ]

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("page", "blogs_category")


class PostPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey("PostPage", related_name="post_tags")       

class PostPage(Page):
    header_image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )

    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through="blogs.PostPageTag", blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ImageChooserPanel("header_image"),
        InlinePanel("categories", label="category"),
        FieldPanel("tags"),
    ]
```

Comment: Have you thought about using snippets instead?  I use them to tag different categories on a site I built.  It works very well and has more flexibility if you wanted to add more details to a snippet.  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/snippets.html#id1

Comment: How would I use a snippet here, I have my models.py and template page.

Comment: Also for your answer, how can on the front end see the posts in a specific category for exmaple I SCRC and Libraries, when i choose SCRC i see all the posts for both SCRC and Libraries, so there is a if statement  i need in models.py i think. I added how my models file looks in the intial question post imade.

Answer (score 0):

Snippets are just like any model, except it gets put into a different area of the Wagtail CMS.

Here is a basic example of a snippet in code

```
@register_snippet
class Category(index.Indexed, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        null=True,
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
    ]

    search_fields = [
        index.SearchField('name'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

Here is how you would reference a snippet on a Wagtail Page Model

```
class BlogPost(Page):
    category = ParentalManyToManyField(
            'Category',
            blank=True,
        )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel(
                'category',
                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            )
        ],
            heading='Category'
        ),
    ]
```

You can also remove the `widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple` if that isn't something you want this to do.

By creating a snippet, you now have the option to create "Categories" and then have the ability to select them on the Blog Post.

Once you do that, all you have to do is query the category in the BlogPage model on the HTML template and display it or group it however you want to.

I use snippets when I want more flexibility that tags cannot offer.

---

EDIT
As I was looking through the Wagtail docs I found something that does [exactly what I mentioned](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html#categories)

Comment: Thank you, i found this tutorial but i have two categories, how do i code it in my models file so it only shows each posts that has those categories.

Comment: You can do a simple get request and pass the specific category via the url and then query that url parameter to get only the blog posts with that category.  Same with tags.  The URL would look something like `127.0.0.1:8000/?category=tech` on the backend you would parse the query string and use it to do the db lookup.  `Blog.objects.filter(blog_category__name=qs)` where qs is the parsed query string

Comment: That makes sense, from the code i posted in the first question what do i need to change for your logic to work?